# How to extract all tar.gz files present in multiple folders at a time to another directory?

Tags: linux, centos, tar, extract

There are many folders in my current directory. Each folder has a tar.gz file. To extract the tar.gz file I need to be inside each folder and run the following command every time.

```
tar xvzf tar.gz -C /path/to/targetdirectory
```

Inside my current directory it looks like below:

```
   current directory
            ├──Folder1
                ├── A.tar.gz
            ├──Folder2
                ├── B.tar.gz
            ├──Folder3
                ├── C.tar.gz
            ├──Folder4
                ├── D.tar.gz
            ├──Folder5
                ├── E.tar.gz
```

To extract all at a time I tried like this

```
tar xvzf */*.tar.gz -C /path/to/targetdirectory
```

This gave me an error:

```
tar: Folder1/A.tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: Folder2/B.tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: Folder3/C.tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: Folder4/D.tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: Folder5/E.tar.gz: Not found in archive
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `find` and execute a command on each found file, in the directory of that file:

```
find . -name '*.tar.gz' -execdir tar -xzvf '{}' \;
```

The `-execdir` option executes `tar` from within the folder of the found file, and `{}` will be replaced by the tarfile's name.

See the [`find` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) for more info.

Comment: Where should I give target directory in the command?

Comment: Ok. Gave like this to get the extracted files into target directory. find . -name '*.tar.gz' -execdir tar -C /path/to/targetdirectory -xzvf '{}' \; This worked

Comment: Yep, you can specify the commands as usual within the `-exec` option.

Comment: hi...I have small doubt. Is there a way to give path to those...*.tar.gz files?

Comment: You can `find` in another directory by replacing `find .` with `find /path/to/directory`.

Comment: Here is the complete cmd using different search directory and different target directory:
find /var/www/staging/ -name '*.tar.gz' -execdir tar -C /var/www/target -xzf ' {}' \;

Thanks slhck and beginner for help, this works very well.